# How to remove a specific array by its index

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have a problem with deleting an array from a firebase database. Here is how my database look like

```
Location
   0 "Maldives"
   1 "Maldives"
   2 "India"
```

Sometimes the database contains the same location. when users try to delete a location it deletes all the match matching locations.

Here is the code I used:

```
                                          onPressed: () {
                                            Firestore.instance
                                                .collection('schedules')
                                                .document(data.documentID)
                                                .updateData({
                                              "location":
                                                  FieldValue.arrayRemove(
                                                      ["Maldives"]),

                                            });
                                          },
                                          child: Text(
                                            'Remove',
                                            style: TextStyle(
                                                color: Color(0xFF34495e)),
                                          )),
```

if i  use that code this how database look like:

```
Location
   0 "India"
```

How i can sovle this problem. if we could delete by index of array it will be much more easy. how i can delete?

Answer (score 2):

This is exactly what the [documentation](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/FieldValue.html#.arrayRemove) is stating about the `FieldValue.arrayRemove` method.

If the use case is to preserve one of the "Maldives" value, you should considering storing them differently (maybe in a subcollection) or do the treatment on the client side.